# Update the value of a HTML input field by clicking and dragging (similar to unity3d interface)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, range

Unity has a super cool range slider and I'm having trouble duplicating the functionality for the web.

With unity, you can click on the letter X and drag left, and an input field will show a decreasing number.

If you click on the letter X and drag right, the input field will show an increasing number.

But X does not have a slider, it's always in the same place regardless of the value in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to set a function to mouse down on the element containing the "X" to get the starting position. Then bind a function to mousemove which calculates the difference between the current position and the starting position on the X-axis to determine the value to place in the input field.

Proof of Concept:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95191c56796fb2e4e5cd

Comments are included in the code to explain the processes occurring.

More information:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_clientxy